# Facebook Application's Groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-group

In [this Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/groups/), it's described how to get, create, or delete groups that belongs to the application. But I cannot see these created application groups under my App's page. Where do I have to look for? Am I only able to get these groups by using graph api or are they displayed on App's facebook page?

Comment: No, they are not shown on the app page. They will be shown as a bookmark to users once they joined them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/game-groups#design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons you're not getting to see the group are;
- The group privacy is 'Closed', and
- You're not a member of the group

So, if your group's privacy is "Open", you can directly request;
[https://www.facebook.com/groups/{GROUP-ID}](https://www.facebook.com/groups/)

If not, you first need to join the group. To do so, request;
`POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{GROUP-ID}/members?member={UID}&access_token={APP_TOKEN}`